# Using setCampaignParamsOnNextHit (Android) and the iOS equivalent to attribute users in Google Analytics

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, cordova, google-analytics

After reading the Android API and iOS setup guide for campaign/user attribution in Google's docs, I'm a little confused with how to read out parameters. We're using a third party library to pull in our campaign data, and so I have a list of keys like utm_source, utm_campaign, etc. that led to the user installing the app. I want to tell GA to use these parameters every time it sends an event.

Now, according to the Android guide, it seems like I'll want to use `public void setCampaignParamsOnNextHit (Uri uri)` and re-encode my utm_* variables in a URI format. Does this method need to be called prior to every tracked event?

Android guide: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/Tracker.html#public-methods

The confusion is stemming from what I had read in their iOS guide:
`Note that in the following examples, campaign data is not set on the tracker directly, as it only needs to be sent once`. It doesn't look like I'd need to re-encode any variables as I can just pass in a dictionary here.

iOS guide: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns#general-campaigns

I can code either language to either always call a set method before a track call or just set it once. Though, can anyone provide any clarity with these APIs? Ideally, I'd like to track all events with those original attributes intact.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: Not a great answer, but I worked around it, and included the metadata with every call just to be safe. I don't remember if I tried by setting it only once on iOS.

```iOS:
I stored campaign information locally and I used GAIDictionaryBuilder's _setAll to include my dictionary with utm_* tags before sending out my requests to GA's servers.

Android:
I stored campaign information locally and called setCampaignParamsOnNextHit() before any of my tracking event calls.
```